# IIF statement error when divding by 0

Tags: reporting-services, syntax, reportbuilder3.0, iif, ssrs-expression

Ok so I have an #ERROR when dividing by 0 so I have tried to capture this using the following code

```
=IIf(Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!region.Value, Fields!region.Value, Fields!X.Value, "Dataset2")))=0,"-", Fields!Bad.Value/(Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!region.Value, Fields!region.Value, Fields!ticket_count.Value, "Dataset2")))
```

So this should do the following: If [value in FieldsX in "Dataset2"] = 0, then show a "**-**" , else do the calculation [Fields!Bad.Value/FieldX in "Dataset2"]

But for some reason this just fails upon attempting to run: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.

Is there something wrong with how I have formatted the Iif statement? Because the false calculation runs fine when used independently.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your brackets properly. It's not proper.
Below code may work for you.

```html
=IIf(Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!region.Value, Fields!region.Value, Fields!X.Value, "Dataset2"))=0,"-", Fields!Bad.Value/(Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!region.Value, Fields!region.Value, Fields!ticket_count.Value, "Dataset2"))))
```

Comment: OK that does now run however its still returning an #ERROR - so it looks like its not liking the TRUE part because the false part runs fine if [Field!X.Value in Dataset2] > 0  ---- Any Ideas?

Comment: This may be ur else part is a decimal value and if part is a string. Check by puting some 0 or 1. If it's execute fine then u have to think for some alternatives.

Comment: Yes so if the else part is of Decimal type, can I not convert the true part into a decimal? will this help? (Sorry for pestering, my expressions/report builder knowledge is quite limited)